# Let f be continuous, $f \geq 0$ on the rectangle $R.$ If $\int_R f dA = 0$, prove that $f = 0$ on $R.$

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be continuous, with $f \geq 0$ on the rectangle $R.$ If

$$\int_R f dA = 0,$$ prove that $f = 0$ on $R.$

Comment: Please show what you have done and tried. We are not doing your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose by way of contradiction that $f \not\equiv 0$. This implies that there is some point $P \in R$ such that $f(P) > 0$ and, by continuity, there is a small ball $B_r(P)$ such that $f>0$ on $B_r(P)$. Now split up the integral in a way that exploits this.